# How to Check the AMD Card Installed on my System (Switchable Graphics)

Tags: graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have a Dell laptop and it has the switchable graphics technology. I know what it is all about but if I want to check the specs for the AMD card, from where can I check it?

If I check it in Device manager it just says AMD 8730.

Is there any other utility or a 3rd party software which if I run could show me the name of the dedicated card with the RAM it has like AMD Radeon 2GB.

Comment: You already know what graphics card you have its an `AMD 8730` there is only one model: http://products.amd.com/en-us/mobilitygpuresult.aspx?f1=AMD+Radeon+HD+8000M+Series+GPU&f2=AMD+Radeon+HD+8700M+Series+GPUS&f3=AMD+Radeon%e2%84%a2+HD+8730M+Series+GPU&f4=PCIe+3.0&f5=2048&f6=DDR3&f7=False&f8=11.1&f9=False&f10=False&f11=False&f12=False&f13=True&f14=n%2fa&f15=True&f16=n%2fa&f17=True&f18=False&f19=False&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GPUz](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) is a good choice, very simple and will give you all the information you need.